# Libcurl: sftp directory list is incomplete

Tags: list, directory, sftp, libcurl

I am connected to a SFTP site and require the list of files in a specific directory.
What I get is only one line (so only one file) as if there is a terminator at the end of the string.
This is my code:

My callbacck is:

```
static size_t getRemoteListCallback(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* up)
{ 
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    ((string*)up)->append(buf, realsize);
    return realsize;

}
```

And my code is:

```
void GetRemoteList ()
{
    string fileListBuffer = "";
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_URL, sRemoteURL.c_str());  // Target URL
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &getRemoteListCallback );
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &fileListBuffer );  

    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD,   sUserPassword.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_SSH_AUTH_TYPES, CURLSSH_AUTH_PASSWORD);

    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(m_curl);

....

}
```

Someone have an idea ?

Comment: What do you get back if you connect to the site with an FTP client and issue an `NLST` command? does `sRemoteURL` have an ftp prefix (`ftp://`)? Does anything change if you set `CURLOPT_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL` to ftp? Note that you don't need to initialise `fileListbuffer`.

Comment: I used winscp and filezilla and whit these client I get the complete list of files in the directory. sRemoteURL has  a sftp:// like prefix. I tried to use CURLOPT_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL but anything is changed